# Just cause 2 collectibles/destructibles increased visibility mod

Tags: mods, just-cause-2

I just saw a glitch that turned out to be a feature. The collectible items icons where visible from much farther that usual and the range of the minimap was larger. I liked it so much!, but it only happened for the military base I was at the moment...
I'm going for 100% completion and sometimes it's very boring to have to sweep an area on foot just to find a missing package/small destructible.

Is there any mod that could make the life easier with this? I couldn't find anything at http://www.justcause2mods.com/

Comment: Oh, man, is it ever annoying to search for the last collectible in a huge city or military base while dozens of Panauan soldiers fire at you...

Comment: One word: Nuke!

Answer (score 3):

It's not a mod, but you can load your save game into a [map viewer](http://justcause2mods.com/mods/jc2-map-viewer-updated/) and determine exactly what you need to find and where it is.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately modding for Just Cause 2 is really difficult due to missing tools and SDK. This is probably the reason why the mod you ask for is still not available and probably it will never be.

I hope that for Just Cause 3 they will add more possibilities for modders.

But if it can help, I can say that when I bought the ['Black Market' Aerial Pack DLC](http://justcause.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Market_Aerial_Pack) that contains the cool **Dual Parachute Thrusters** my efficiency in researching collectibles has improved a lot. Thanks to the high maneuverability and the possibility to stay at a good height is really easier find that dammed last crate that you never found.